# Альтернатива циклам в BigQuery, есть ли?

Tags: sql, bigquery

Сразу скажу, что с BigQuery я знаком поверхностно, но есть задача, которую необходимо решить средствами этой системы не прибегая к использованию иных инструментов. Суть в том, что BigQuery не позволяет использовать циклы, а как без них решить эту задачу, я не представляю. Может быть у кого-то есть мысли на этот счет, и вы сможете подсказать, в какую сторону копать?

Сама задача звучит так. Есть таблица с данными, где за каждую дату есть набор IDшек пользователей - каждый день появляются новые пользователи (впервые), исчезают старые, а какие-то сохраняются (были ранее). Нужно вычислить за каждую дату, какое кол-во пользователей из текущей даты есть в следующие N, при этом их нет в предыдущей. Например, кол-во пользователей из ячейки за 2 января, есть за 3-6 января, но их не было 1-го января.

Кол-во дат конечное, но диапазон плавающий (может быть 5 дат, может быть 50, и т.д.) - именно по этому и возникают мысли о цикле, а как решить без него, не представляю.

Другими словами для наглядности-

Дано:

```
date            id    
01.01.2019       1     
01.01.2019       2     
01.01.2019       3     
01.01.2019       4
01.01.2019       5
02.01.2019       2
02.01.2019       3 
02.01.2019       4
03.01.2019       1
03.01.2019       2
03.01.2019       5
03.01.2019       6
04.01.2019       1
04.01.2019       2
04.01.2019       7
```

На выходе нужно получить такую таблицу:

```
---- 1день 2день 3день 4день 
1янв   5     3     3     2 
2янв   3     1     1     -
3янв   4     2     -     - 
4янв   3     -     -     -
```

Признателен любой помощи, очень много чего уже перечитал, но применить на деле не получилось.

Comment: Какой цикл? зачем? 2 копии таблицы, синтетическая таблица чисел от 1 до заданного максимума, группировка да crosstab().

Comment: Признателен вам, и рад что эту задачу можно решить не прибегая к циклам. Прочитаю все предложенные методы, но к сожалению пока совершенно не понимаю как их сгруппировать и применить.

Comment: Делайте fiddle (или хотя бы выложите скрипт создания и наполнения таблицы). И укажите версию SQL-сервера.

Comment: Как уже писал выше, выгружаю данные из BigQuery. Наполнение таблицы идет автоматически при выполнении пользователем того или иного действия в приложении. В данном случае пытаюсь посчитать пользователей зашедших в первые и дальнейшие заходы в приложение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM CROSSTAB('WITH RECURSIVE nums (num) AS (
                 SELECT 0
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT num+1 
                 FROM nums 
                 WHERE num < (SELECT MAX(ddate) - MIN(ddate) 
                              FROM test)
              )
SELECT t1.ddate::DATE, nums.num::INT, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.id)::INT cnt_id
FROM test t1, test t2, nums
WHERE t1.ddate + nums.num = t2.ddate AND t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.ddate, nums.num
ORDER BY 1,2')
AS ct("date" DATE, "1 day" INT, "2 days" INT, "3 days" INT, "4 days" INT);
```

> BigQuery does not support WITH RECURSIVE

Тогда статическая таблица чисел:

```
SELECT *
FROM CROSSTAB('
SELECT t1.ddate::DATE, nums.num::INT, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.id)::INT cnt_id
FROM test t1, test t2, nums
WHERE t1.ddate + nums.num = t2.ddate 
  AND t1.id = t2.id
  AND nums.num <= (SELECT MAX(ddate) - MIN(ddate) 
                  FROM test)
GROUP BY t1.ddate, nums.num
ORDER BY 1,2')
AS ct("date" date, "1 day" INT, "2 days" INT, "3 days" INT, "4 days" INT);
```

Или динамическая:

```
SELECT *
FROM CROSSTAB('
SELECT t1.ddate::DATE, nums.num::INT, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.id)::INT cnt_id
FROM test t1, test t2, 
     (SELECT 0::INT num UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) nums
WHERE t1.ddate + nums.num = t2.ddate 
  AND t1.id = t2.id
  AND nums.num <= (SELECT MAX(ddate) - MIN(ddate) 
                  FROM test)
GROUP BY t1.ddate, nums.num
ORDER BY 1,2')
AS ct("date" date, "1 day" INT, "2 days" INT, "3 days" INT, "4 days" INT);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b0b9f6d022f567688551ed7335f3fee2)

Comment: В любом случае благодарен вам за пример, постараюсь его адаптировать для других задач, но BigQuery does not support WITH RECURSIVE. К сожалению(

Comment: @LonelYNighTWolF Это поправимо. См. fiddle.

Comment: Ох, мне кажется что у меня не получиться довести до ума эту не столь сложную задачу, и не удобно тратить чужое время, но BigQuery does not support CROSSTAB. Пытаюсь нагуглить обход.

Comment: Блин, всё забываю, что BigQuery - там был изначально тег постгресса, и он в башке засел... в общем. как получить линейные данные, я показывал (собственно, текст подзапроса в CROSSTAB - это оно и есть). А дальше эмулировать пивот - см. напр. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272514/how-to-pivot-table-in-big-query или там https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Pivot-Transform_57344645